# error registering spark UDF from external jar

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to register a UDF from the jar, by doing the following process:

1. define a Trait in the main class
2. extend and overwrite the function from the trait to write the UDF logic and register.
3. using the UDF function in main jar as part of sql.
   here the sample code from the main jar

```
    def registerExternalUDF(externaljarClassName:String,spark:SparkSession)
    {
        val extUDF:ExternalUDF=Class.forname(externaljarClassName).newInstance().asInstanceOf[ExternalUDF]
        extUDF.createAndRegisterUDF(spark)
    }
```

here the sample code from the external jar class

```
override def createAndRegisterUDF(spark:SparkSession){
val fn=<logic>
spark.udf.register("fn",fn)
}
```

error:
couldn't paste the full error due to organization policy

```
no class found error: scala/runtime/lambaDeserialize
```

Comment: Sounds like an issue with different Scala versions bt not sure.

Comment: The issue is with object deserialization  but i cant seem to resolve it